# PHP Form and validation

Tags: javascript, forms

I have code that check for empty input forms and it works fine. But I want to check for digits also for phone number field. I don't want people to enter alphabet in phone field?

How to make that validation ?

```
function validate() {
var phone=document.forms["contactForma"]["email"].value;
var name = document.forms["contactForma"]["ime"].value;
if (name == "") {
    alert('Please enter your name');
    return false;
}
if (phone == "") {
    alert('Please enter your Mobile Number');
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: That is not PHP it's javascript

Comment: Phone numbers a better represented as text, not numbers. Otherwise you will run into trouble with +, ( , ), and leading zeros.

Comment: This is javascript, not PHP. Anyway, use regular expressions or force the user to only be able to digit numbers on that field. You have many ways to do that, just try something. You can also check if the value is a number, anyway, but it won't match commas.

Answer (score 0):

The isNaN() function determines whether a value is an illegal number (Not-a-Number).
This function returns true if the value is NaN, and false if not.

Check whether a number is an illegal number:

**Example:**

```
if (phone != "" || isNaN(phone)) 
{
      alert("Invalid number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (phone != "") {
    var reg = /^\d+$/;
    return phone.test(reg)
}
```

Or, do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. This is solution

```
function validate() {
var phone=document.forms["contactForma"]["email"].value;
var name = document.forms["contactForma"]["ime"].value;
if (name == "") {
    alert('Please enter your name');
    return false;
}
if (phone == "") {
    alert('Please enter your Mobile Number');
    return false;
}

if (phone != "" || isNaN(phone)) 
{
  alert("Invalid number");
   return false;
}

}
```

Comment: I would rather prefer the regexp method. This method would not work well on phonenumbers as they may contain spaces and or a "+"-character, read up on the regexp method it's very useful, you can check for patterns and much more! http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Also you may want to trim your phone number first aswell (remove whitespaces from beginning and end)

Anyhow you can change (phone != "" || isNaN(phone))  to (isNaN(phone)) instead as you already have the emptycheck above.